# how to get saved queries in tfs 2012 using c#

Tags: c#

I need to get the queries in TFS 2012 in the "My Queries" folder. I found [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx). But following that gives all the queries.

[image: Folder Hierarchy]

I want to get queries from the "My Queries" folder. This is what i have tried so far:

```
string selectedProject = this.listProjects.SelectedItem.ToString();
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TFSDetail.GetTeamProjectDetails(UrlPath);
if (teamProjectCollection != null)
{
     Project detailsOfTheSelectedProject = null;
     WorkItemStore workItemStore = 
           (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

     string folder = "My Queries";
     var project = workItemStore.Projects[selectedProject];
     QueryHierarchy queryHierarchy = project.QueryHierarchy;
     var queryFolder = queryHierarchy as QueryFolder;
     QueryItem queryItem = queryFolder[folder];
     queryFolder = queryItem as QueryFolder;               
}
```

When i add `queryFolder` to watch it gives following output:

[image: Watch Window]

How an I access the result and get those values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem following way:

```
var project = workItemStore.Projects[selectedProject];
QueryHierarchy queryHierarchy = project.QueryHierarchy;
var queryFolder = queryHierarchy as QueryFolder;
QueryItem queryItem = queryFolder[folder];
queryFolder = queryItem as QueryFolder;
foreach (var item in queryFolder)
{
     listQueries.Items.Add(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: @AnkitB its string variable. You can see that detail in question

Comment: thanks, Can you tell me how I can get the List of Query folders? So that I can Show the query Hierarchy? If I dnt know name of Folder While retrieving query Items